# android 2 activities on the same screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've a tabBar with 4 tabs, the Main tab is the first one, and when I click the second one I want do display another activity above the main activity in the half of the screen, reducing the opacity of the main. I'm doing this with a Dialog but it's not the result I want. What are the best way to do this?

example image

[image: http://s9.postimg.org/e24pqpl3z/Untitled.jpg]

Comment: You can try fragments

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), this seems like the perfect time to use them.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 options to achieve what you want.

- Second activity can be dialog (You already said you do it but you don't like).
- Using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). (recommended)
- Using layouts by playing with visibility, (not recommended in your case)

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities